# Segmentation fault while system() in C

Tags: c, terminal, segmentation-fault

I want to use the "base64" script of linux to encode the data and get it in C.
When I try to compile

```
char a[200];
strcpy(a, "Hello");
printf("%s", a);
```

I get the output

```
Hello
```

Now whenever I try the code

```
char a[200];
strcpy(a, system("echo Hello | base64"));
printf("%s", a);
```

I get the output

```
aGVsbG8K
Segmentation fault
```

Even when I remove the "printf" statement, I get the same

```
aGVsbG8K
Segmentation fault
```

I want to save the value of the output of

```
system("echo Hello | base64")
```

in 'a' and not display it. Please help

Comment: Do yourself a favour: Read `man gcc` and in particular the part about warnings. If you had turned these on, the compiler would have told you that there's something fishy going on between the returnvalue of `system()` and the input for `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
strcpy(a, system("echo Hello | base64"));
```

`system()` doesn't stores it's result into array a as `system()` job is to execute the `command` provided in the argument & print it on console i.e `stdout` buffer. From the manual page of [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

> `system()`  executes a command specified in `command` by calling
>   `/bin/sh -c`
>          command, and returns after the command has been completed.

There is one way to solve the problem i.e instead of printing `system()` output on `stdout` you can redirect its *output to a file* & then *read that from file* & print. For example

```
int main(void) {
        close(1); /* stdout file descriptor is avilable now */
        /* create the file if doesn't exist, if exist truncate the content to 0 length */
        int fd = open("data.txt",O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_RDWR,0664); /* fd gets assigned with lowest 
                                                  available fd i.e 1 i.e nowonwards stdout output 
                                                  gets rediredcted to file */
        if(fd == -1) {
                /* @TODO error handling */
                return 0;
        }
        system("echo Hello | base64"); /* system output gets stored in file */
        int max_char = lseek(fd,0,2);/* make fd to point to end, get the max no of char */
        char *a = malloc(max_char + 1); /* to avoid buffer overflow or 
                underflow, allocate memory only equal to the max no of char in file */
        if(a == NULL) {
                /* @TODO error handling if malloc fails */
                return 0;
        }
        lseek(fd,0,0);/* from beginning of file */
        int ret = read(fd,a,max_char);/* now read out put of system() from
                                          file as array and print it */
        if(ret == -1) {
                /* @TODO error handling */
                return 0;
        }
        a[ret] = '\0';/* \0 terminated array */
        dup2(0,fd);/*fd 0 duplicated to file descriptor where fd points i.e */
        printf("output : %s \n", a);
        /* to avoid memory leak, free the dynamic memory */
        free(a);
        return 0;
}
```

My above suggestion is a temporary fix & I won't recommend this, instead use [popen] as suggested by @chris Turner (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) which says

> The `popen()` function opens a process by creating a pipe,  forking, 
>   and
>          invoking  the shell.  Since a pipe is by definition unidirectional, the
>          type argument may specify  only  **reading**  or  **writing**,  not  both;  the
>          resulting stream is correspondingly read-only or write-only.

For example

```
int main(void) {
        char buf[1024];
        FILE *fp = popen("echo Hello | base64","r");
        printf("%s\n",fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you use `printf` to write output if you've closed stdout?

Comment: `open("data.txt",O_RDWR|0664);`??!?!  That won't create the file if it doesn't exist.  You're misusing the `flags` argument to `open()` and missing the `mode` argument.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html  Then, you're assuming it's safe to call `dup2(0,fd)` in an attempt to restore `stdout` without knowing of `stdin` is safe for writing.  You'd do much better to `dup()` the `stdin` file number **before** closing it to save it.  Third, you risk a buffer overrun if your `read()` call fills the `a` buffer.

Comment: I've edited @AndrewHenle Can you recheck it ? As per my understanding `dup2(0,fd);` doesn't disturb other regular fd's like `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

Answer (score 6):

If you read the documentation for `system` you'll discover that it doesn't return a string - it's defined as:

```
int system(const char *command);
```

The return value is the return status of the command or -1 if there's an error. You can't get the output using `system` - the output of the command(s) you run will go straight to stdout.

To get the output from another command you could use something like `popen`.

```
FILE *myfile;
char buffer[1024];

myfile=popen("echo Hello | base64","r");
if(myfile)
  {
  while(fgets(buffer,1024,myfile))
    {
    printf("%s",buffer);
    }

  pclose(myfile);
  }
```